# Angular: handle object changes in ngFor, force print

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ngfor, ngonchanges

I have my `app.component` with a list of objects

```
class Hero {
    alias: string;

    constructor(public firstName: string,
                public lastName: string) {
    }
}

class AppComponent {
...
heroes: Hero[] = [
    new Hero("foo", "bar")
];
...
onHeroChange($event: Hero, index: number): void {
    this.heroes[index] = $event;
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes; let index=index">
  <hero [hero]="hero" (heroChange)="onHeroChange($event, index)"></hero>
</div>
```

The **HeroComponent** is

```
export class HeroComponent {
  @Input()
  set hero(newValue: Hero) {
    this._hero = newValue;
    this.showAlias = !!newValue.alias;
  }

  get hero(): Hero {
    return this._hero;
  }

  @Output() heroChange: EventEmitter<Hero> = new EventEmitter<Hero>();
  showAlias: boolean = !1;

  private _hero: Hero;

  //

  @HostListener('click')
  onHeroClick(): void {
    this.hero.alias = `alias_${+new Date()}`;
    console.info('HERO TO EMIT', this.hero);
    this.heroChange.emit(this.hero);
  }
}
```

My problem is that even by assigning the changed hero in `app.component`, the `set hero` inside `hero.component` is not called, so `showAlias` in the example is not updated and I don't see the alias in the `hero.component`.

Do I need to force the ngFor by assigning the entire array?

Maybe a workaround could be removing the object from the array and then inserting again?
Sounds like useless computation though.

**Note**: this is just an example, it's not what I'm really working on, so something like

> Update the showAlias prop in the onHeroClick method

or

> Assign hero in the hero.component

unfortunately don't solve the issue. I need the changes to be on the outside because other stuff happens.

Could be another option changing the detection to `onPush` and marking for check manually?

Blitz ==> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kpn3ds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting a new `hero`, you're just modifying a property on the existing one:

```
this.hero.alias = `alias_${+new Date()}`;
```

That doesn't fire the setter. Change the line like this:

```
this.hero = {...this.hero, alias: `alias_${+new Date()}`};
```

Comment: Thanks, but I mentioned that this wouldn't solve. 
The change must be reflected from the array, this would fire the setter inside hero.component too early.

Comment: I might be mistaking, but it seems to me that you're not setting anything. Why would that fire a setter? Your modifying a `hero` object on `HeroComponent`, emitting that same object to `AppComponent` which is passing that same object again to `HeroComponent`. No reference has changed, no setter has been called. Why do you expect something different?

Comment: If you look at the `app.component` you'll see that the new hero is assigned there. 
And I don't expect a setter to fire. I'm asking for a clean solution, to trigger the ngFor to print again.

Comment: It's not a new hero. It's a reference to the same old (just modified) hero, coming from `HeroComponent`. The `ngFor` IS printing again, but the hero that `HeroComponent` gets from this new `ngFor` cycle is the same one as before. Angular change detection uses reference by default. In order to change the reference in AppComponent you could do this: `this.heroes[index] = {...$event};`

Comment: Yeah actually you're right about that! In the original code I create an entirely new object, but it doesn't work anyway, if I remember correctly. Anyway I'll try in my Blitz and see what happens! Thanks

Comment: Damn! It actually works! Now I have to figure what happened this morning...

Comment: Depending on how complex your real use case is, another solution would be to define a separate component for the alias. Since that would be bound to the `alias` property (not the whole object), change detection would work without the need of treating `hero` as immutable: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yhpv3j](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yhpv3j)

Comment: Yep. I see what you mean, nice idea!

Comment: I marked your answer as accepted, since you actually pointed me in the right direction! 
Thanks!